# checking if a file already exist using VBA powerpoint

Tags: vba, macros, powerpoint

I want to check if A FileName already exist. What i wrote works perfectly when i test it in my local Desktop. But all the FileNames are saved in a Sharepoint. When I tested it there, it doesn't work! I get always the error message: **bad file Name or number.**
This is what i wrote:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim NewFileName             As String
Dim OwnPathName             As String

oldWeekDay = Weekday(Now)

Select Case oldWeekDay

Case 1
    NewFileName = "PT PM Weekly " & Format(Date + 4, "yyyymmdd")
Case 2
    NewFileName = "PT PM Weekly " & Format(Date + 3, "yyyymmdd")
Case 3
    NewFileName = "PT PM Weekly " & Format(Date + 2, "yyyymmdd")
Case 4
    NewFileName = "PT PM Weekly " & Format(Date + 1, "yyyymmdd")
Case 5
    NewFileName = "PT PM Weekly " & Format(Date, "yyyymmdd")
Case 6
    NewFileName = "PT PM Weekly " & Format(Date + 6, "yyyymmdd")
Case 7
    NewFileName = "PT PM Weekly " & Format(Date + 5, "yyyymmdd")

End Select

OwnPathName = ActivePresentation.Path
FullFileName = OwnPathName & "\" & NewFileName

'for debug only (can remove it later)
'MsgBox OwnPathName
'MsgBox FullFileName


 Dim StrFile             As String
 Dim FileFound           As Boolean

 FileFound = False
 'look for all types of PowerPoint files only (filter only to PowerPoint files to save time)
 StrFile = Dir(OwnPathName & "\*pptm*")

 Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
 If InStr(StrFile, NewFileName) > 0 Then
    FileFound = True
    Exit Do
End If
StrFile = Dir
Loop

If FileFound Then
MsgBox "Modification already done"
Else
RemoveTextboxes
AllBlackAndDate
SaveAllPresentations (FullFileName)
End If

End Sub
```

I don't understand why it doesn't work!
Can you help me please to get solve the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: My OwnpathName = https://sec-ishare.infineon.com/sites/MC_PM/Shared%20Documents/09_Reporting/PT/2016

Answer (score 0):

I think this may work, I use it all the time to loop through directories on my PC or any network I have access to.

```
F = Dir(StrFile, 7)  'sets f equal to the first file name
Do While F <> ""        'loops until there are no more files in the directory

 If InStr(StrFile, NewFileName) > 0 Then
    FileFound = True
    Exit Do
 End If  

  F = Dir            'set f equal to the next file name in the directory

Loop
```